# get line of a predefined sentence that in a txt file line?

Tags: python

so i have this code:

```
for line in open('music.txt'):
    if 'file : "' in line:


        c = line.split('file : "')

        del c[0]

        d="".join(c)

        a=re.sub('"','',d)

        e=re.sub(',','',a)


        urls.append(e)
```

Is there a way to do this but without a file?

Comment: Can you specify what you mean by 'without a file'?  Do you mean you want to read stdin?

Comment: well because i getting source code from a website and write it to a file and i can probobly write it to a list and maybe search it with the re module?

Comment: The code is pretty ugly... What it's supposed to do?

Comment: it writes the sites source code and gets the url line for the mp3 file and formats the code to get only the url.

Comment: Do you understand any of the code in question? What do you really want to do?

Comment: yes i wrote it and im aware that it is not the best way to do it for this situation but it was nessecary for when i added it to my main project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you want something like that:

```
urls = [re.findall(r'file : "(.*)"', line)[0].replace(',', '')
        for line in file if 'file :' in line]
```

and it works on any file object or list.

For standard input, use `file = sys.stdin`

Example:

```
file = ['file : "test, 123, 456, abcde"', 
        'other line', 
        'file : "zzzzzzzzz"]
```

output:

```
['test 123 456 abcde', 'zzzzzzzzz']
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to read from standard input (for example, in a pipeline) then you can just write

```
import sys
for line in sys.stdin:
```

And the rest will work. (`sys.stdin` is an open file corresponding to standard input)

If you have the lines in a list, then you can just iterate across the list using the same code.